# Add Target Not Working Swift 3 - UIButton inside a UIStackView

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, swift3

I am trying to add a UIButton to a stackview programatically which is a part of custom UIView class. The issue is if I try to add a target with the selector from the Custom UIView class, the selector is never fired on tapping the button. But if i give it a selector from my UIViewController it works fine.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here ?

```
self.isUserInteractionEnabled = false;
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor;
    self.expandCollapseButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero);
    self.expandCollapseButton!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(OMLiquidActionButton.expandButtonActionHandler(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside);

    self.mainContainer = UIStackView(frame:CGRect.zero);
    self.mainContainer?.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
    self.mainContainer?.axis = .vertical;
    self.mainContainer?.distribution = .equalSpacing;
    //Add the maincontainer/stackview to the parentview

    //add the view to the container
    self.mainContainer?.addArrangedSubview(self.expandCollapseButton!);

    self.parentView?.addSubview(self.mainContainer!);
```

Please Note: Constraints are already defined for the view programatically and button exists as the topmost view.

Comment: Why are you not using `addArrangedSubview`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggesting it but it has nothing to do with the UIResponder class. I am not able to understand why I am not able to register a selector in same UIView class.

Comment: The view hierarchy is related to the responder chain. When you set it up in the view controller are you adding it to a stack view in this weird way?

Comment: parentView = superView. Main Container = StackView. I already changed the as suggested above but still the problem exists

Comment: Could you post a little more code? Which class is your code snipped from? Why is `isUserInteractionEnabled = false`? Why is the frame of the mainContainer set to zero?